# What is the git extensions icon in this submodule?

Tags: git-extensions

I am using submodules in git extensions. There's an icon in the left hand side with a small red exclamation mark on the folder (second icon down from the top).

What does this mean? The online manual does not say.

[image: Git extensions folder red icon]

I have uploaded the image above, found on this website.

https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/4281#issue-284627800

Comment: Is this git-gui?

Comment: It's in git extensions, the lower left hand pane. It might be common to the git gui, I don't know.